# Modify Json Data ( adding wrapper bracket)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a json response

```
{
"name" : "xxx",
"address":"xxx"
}
```

How I can change this like the below example

```
cd(
   {
    "name" : "xxx",
    "address":"xxx"
    }
)
```

I am using c# to get the response and send it back

Comment: your expected format is not JSON

Comment: I am saying, not asking :P

Comment: How you want to use it?

Comment: Real issue is we have already made json data and one client is asking for a formatted out put like the above (with 'cb'). So I thought to create a class to call my old project and edit the json and give a new response

Comment: That's not possible. because expected format is not json. You can give him string though.

Comment: okay, I understood, but any way to format it

Answer (score 0):

You can return json result from web api in this way:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {cd=YourDataList});
```

and also add ***"Newtonsoft.Json" package*** from nuget.org to your project so then add this codes to webApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            }
```

Comment: This won't solve my issue, I need in a specif format. When I try to format I am not able to serialize it and send the response. I have to wrap my response in a cd. That is what issue